# Causality/Non-Causality, One/Two-sided integral transform (Laplace, Fourier), Discrete case

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, causality

When introducing **unilateral** and **bilateral integral transforms** (in the context of Laplace transform), I have problems understanding how **causality** and **non-causality** are expressed when considering the (finite) discrete case using DFT or Z-Transformation.

In general, bilateral transformations are said to be used for the application of non-causal systems

$$F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt, \quad \stackrel{discrete}{\longrightarrow} \quad F(s)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n]\ e^{-s T}.  $$

Similarly, unilateral transformations are said to be used for causal systems (restricting the integral limits to positive values)

$$F(s) = \int_{0}^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt, \quad \stackrel{discrete}{\longrightarrow} \quad F(s)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f[n]\ e^{-s T}.$$

One may use the convolution operator to introduce the concepts

$$ \text{Causal:} \qquad y \left( t \right) = \int_0^\infty f(\tau) g(t - \tau)\, d\tau,$$

$$ \text{Non-causal:} \qquad y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) g(t - \tau)\, d\tau,$$

$$\text{Anti-causal:} \qquad y(t) =\int _0^\infty f(\tau) g(t + \tau)\, d\tau.$$

It would be nice if someone can give a simple explanation what it means to speak of causality by merely restricting the integral limits and how this is understood in the specific case applying the DFT or Z-transform to a given (finite) dataset/function $f(t), f[n]$.

Comment: I suppose it is linked to the fact that the first $y(t)$ depends on the values of $g(s)$ only for $s\leq t$, so the preceding times, the past, hence it is called causal?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, seems so. In a time dependant system with actual time $t=0$ the output behaviour is generally only dependant on seen existing values. The integral limits and index sets have more of a formal mathematical meaning.